# IOS-Data is displaying only in iphone 5s ios 9.1 simulater, But data is not displaying in other simulaters

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, xamarin.forms

Data is Showing Only in iphone 5s 9.1 simulater only, but not data is not showing any other simulators including in my device and my simulator size is also increase a lot for iphone 6s simulator.

When i am run my IOS app in iPhone 5s 9.1 simulator data is showing like as below image..

[image]

but, same project run in iPhone 6s 9.1 simulator data is not showing, like as below image.

[image]

What is the reason for that please help, where i did mistake.

Comment: How do you get your datas?

Comment: getting data from sqlite database and bind to table view  in UI.

Comment: database on a webService or locally?

Comment: Do you create it or copy it?

Comment: Copying to device storage.

Comment: Because if you copy it you must set it as a resource in order to work on device. You can set this in the project setting of your project

Comment: @abarbier  settings for database or project..?

Comment: where can i find resource option..

Comment: In "build phases" in your project setting there is a Copy Bundle Resources phase

Comment: But actually I'm not sure this will be the solution since you also have this problem in the simulator

Comment: here is my link to solution explore image once check it, http://1drv.ms/1RhdioH

Comment: Oh Devi I'm so sorry I didn't realise your were creating your app with xamarin (are you using Visual Studio?). My guess would be to check in the root of your project (IndianCinema with the pink icon)

Comment: No i am using Xamarin

Comment: Here is my setting page image for my solution, please check it, http://1drv.ms/1JX3zM1

Comment: Devi I'm sorry but I've no idea on how works Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

You can try different things it looks like there is no data on your list view so try the same thing you are doing but with mock up data and see if this data is being rendered.

Also it looks like the list view is being rendered but it may worth to color (use background color property) it so you can detect which layouts are being showed.

I am not sure about it but you can also check your custom cell and how are they being showed, it may be a good idea to debug the View Model that you are using for filling the List View.